# Volley Post method gives me unexpected response code 400?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Here am new for android development am trying to post json value to server using gson lib i have converted into json but when i try to send to server is throws 400 unexpected response code here let me post my code:

```
listobj = account_sf_db.toServer();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());
 final String yog = gson.toJson(listobj);

    String URL = "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/xxx/CRM/AcoountCreatePageLoad.svc/xxt/xxxt/ " +yog ;




            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            String resp = response.toString();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                }
            })

    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("god", yog);


        return params;
    }  @Override
       public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Accept","application/json");
                    headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");
                    return headers;
                }

    };
         queue.add(stringRequest);
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

400 status code is for `Bad Request`, it means server is not expecting this type of request.

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Please check headers(content-type, user agent,etc.) you are adding whether it is required or not. It might happen that server is expecting a simple request and not `json` request.

Also try to read out error you get in `onErrorResponse`. Server might have responded you the expected parameter and request type, and also discuss the type of API developed by the web developer.

Comment: What parameters does your server expect? I see you are posting the JSON-data as the parameter `god`. Is `god` the correct parameter name, or could this be the cause of the `400 - Bad request` that you get?

Comment: @Yog We cannot expect the perfect answer, even server(web dev.) can throw exceptions manually, as we can throw in Andorid/Java. So it is better to discuss the request type, headers and parameters with Web dev. also give response from errorResponse to dev.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your url after the /xxt/xxxt/

String URL = "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/xxx/CRM/AcoountCreatePageLoad.svc/xxt/xxxt/ " +yog ;

Remove it and I think you'll be fine.

**P.S** 400 generally means there is something wrong with the Url or parameters.